# wamp/Apache - new virtual host that exists outside of /wamp/www

Tags: apache, virtualhost, wampserver, document-root

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` file looks something like this. I am trying to create 2 virtual hosts. One of the projects exists within the default document root, while the other is off on another hard drive altogether.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project1/public_html"
    ServerName p1.localhost
    ServerAlias www.p1.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/p1.localhost.log"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "E:/Other Media/www"
    ServerName pn.localhost
    ServerAlias www.pn.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/pn.localhost.log"
    CustomLog "logs/pn.localhost.log" common
    <Directory "E:/Other Media/www">
        Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added this chunk into my `httpd.conf`

```
<Directory "E:/Other Media/www">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

As expected, the VH in the `/wamp/www` works file, but the project on my `E:` drive will not show up!!

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving everything to [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/). It handles external disk locations MUCH more gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is other easily solution for that. one you can find here , http://www.tech99.us/wamp-configuring-virtual-directory/

by using wamp> apache>alias>add alias you can configure outside directory very easily.